# connecting to mongodb on ec2 instance using the private IP address

Tags: mongodb, aws, amazon-ec2

Im trying to connect to my MongoDB that is on my EC2 instance. I am able to connect to using the public dns with this statement:

> mongoClient = new
>   MongoClient("ec2-3-92-197-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com", 27021);

but if I tried to replace the "ec2-3-92...." with the private IP address, as such:

> mongoClient = new MongoClient("172.31.90.193", 27021);

It gives me the error:

> INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server
>   172.31.90.193:27021 com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
>   java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)   at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
>     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
>     ... 3 more
>
> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed
>   out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster
>   state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=172.31.90.193:27021,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed
>   out}}]    at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:182)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:136)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:94)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:249)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:172)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:132)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:86)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.forEach(MongoIterableImpl.java:110)
>     at App.main(App.java:46)

Is there something I'm missing that is preventing me from connecting to mongo using the private IP address?

I have set up the inbound rules as such:

[image]

and this is what my mongod.conf file looks like:

```
  # mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data. systemLog:   destination: file   logAppend: true   path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data. storage:   dbPath: /var/lib/mongo   journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs processManagement:   fork: true  # fork and run in background   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile   timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces net:   port: 27017
#  bindIp: 172.31.90.193  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:   replSetName: Midterm sharding:   clusterRole: configsvr
## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Note: I have not set any permission or add credentials in my admin db's collection.

Comment: From which machine you are connecting to the MongoDB in aws EC2? Both the machines are in same VPC or connected through internet?

Comment: In trying to connect my local machine to the EC2 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to connect to the MongoDB in EC2 instance from your local machine, the connection should be made via the public network (Internet).

If it is a public network you should use either **Public IP** or **Elastic IP** for the connection.

You cannot use **Private IP** to connect to MongoDB running in AWS EC2 via the public network.